# Execute two threads in parallel and restart the first one when it ends instead of waiting for both to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two methods in Java and I execute them in parallel in a class which has a fixed delay. The first thread takes a few minutes to complete, while the second one can take some hours. What I want is to restart the first thread and execute it when it ends, instead of waiting for the second one to finish and re-execute both of them.
Can anyone help me with this?
My code is below:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30) 
    public void scheduled_function() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Callable<Void> callableSchedule = new Callable<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception
            {
                getAndUpdateSchedule();
                return null;
            }
        };

        Callable<Void> callableMatches = new Callable<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception
            {
                processMatches();
                return null;
            }
        };

        //add to a list
        List<Callable<Void>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
        taskList.add(callableSchedule);
        taskList.add(callableMatches);

        //create a pool executor with  threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        try
        {
            //start the threads
            executor.invokeAll(taskList);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
           System.out.println("An InterruptedException occured");
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just calling the method twice in your `call()` method?  Could you just put `getAndUpdateSchedule();` in twice in a row?  If not, please explain what the restrictions here are.  Or do you want it to repeat more than twice?  If so, you're going to need to explain what you want in much more detail.

Comment: I would like to execute it continuously, not only once or twice. because this methods takes a few minutes to execute and the other one takes more than one hour, I want the first one to execute as much as possible, until the second one finishes

Comment: Ok, that's important.  Do you have a (thread-safe) way of knowing if your task is completed?  Or do you want that logic implemented externally?  Also, you mention a delay in your question, but then you say you want the first task to repeat as soon as it finishes.  Is it fixed-delay, or as fast as possible?

Comment: I do not have a thread-safe way of knowing the task is completed - let's say it is as fast as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store a boolean variable, let's call it `isComplete`, that stores whether the long task has completed or not.  This will be an instance variable, since we need it to stay around after `scheduled_function()` returns.  Something like this:

```java
private boolean isComplete = false;
```

Now, right now this variable is meaningless because we never update it.  So, we need to make sure to update this variable when the long task completes:

```java
Callable<Void> callableMatches = new Callable<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception
    {
        processMatches();

        synchronized (MyClass.this) { // MyClass is just a placeholder name
            isComplete = true;
        }

        return null;
    }
};
```

Notice that where I update the `isComplete` variable, I put it in a synchronized block.  This ensures that the value we are writing is actually going to be updated on the other thread, and it prevents the other thread from reading while we're writing the value.  The result is that the other thread always gets the updated value.

This bit is tangential to the answer, but we can actually shorten this piece of code significantly by using lambda syntax.  `Callable` is a functional interface, so this is perfectly legal:

```java
Callable<Void> callableMatches = () -> {
    processMatches();

    synchronized (MyClass.this) { // MyClass is just a placeholder name
        isComplete = true;
    }

    return null;
};
```

Now all we have to do is check this variable every time we want to start the short task.  Since we only have 2 threads, and one of the threads is being used for the long task, we know that this task will always be executed on the same thread.  This means there's no point in going back to the executor, we can just put it in a while loop inside the callable.  On every iteration of the while loop, we just need to check our `isComplete` variable, and we'll break out of the loop if the other task has completed.

```java
Callable<Void> callableSchedule = () -> {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (MyClass.this) { // MyClass is just a placeholder name
            if (isComplete) {
                break;
            }
        }

        getAndUpdateSchedule();
    }

    return null;
};
```

Note that in this example, I've used the lambda syntax and I've put the if statement inside another synchronized block.  As I explained above, we don't want to get a stale value here and keep looping after the other task is complete.

Comment: thank you, I tried and it seems to work :D

Comment: "This ensures that the value we are writing is actually going to be written to the main memory...", there is no such thing as "main memory". This works because `JLS` says that `synchronized` gives proper `happens-before` guarantees, when used correctly. You did use it correctly - it is there for both reads and writes against the shared variable, it's just that your wording can be improved a bit.

Comment: @Eugene I see what you're saying.  The JLS only guarantees a "happens-before" relationship, but it is typically implemented by writing to main memory.  There isn't really another great way to do it though, because otherwise the incoming thread would have to read from the outgoing thread's memory, which seems like a very bad idea.  So it's really a JLS vs. implementation thing.  I have updated the wording, though, because you're right, there could be an implementation that does it differently, the only guarantees are what the JLS says.  Thank you!

Comment: there isn't "main memory", `synchronized` (among others) are implemented via flushing the store buffer and cache coherence protocol taking care of the rest. But this will never be specified in the official java language specification.

Comment: @Eugene I'll admit I'm not a multithreading guru, but if I google the synchronized keyword, I get tutorials like [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html#synchronized-and-data-visibility) saying the value is written to main memory, and it seems that the JLS mentions [shared memory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1) (just not in conjunction with the synchronized keyword).  Am I missing something about synchronization?  I understand that it's not quite as simple as "all implementations do this."

Comment: `shared memory` really means `shared variables`, as the JLS sort of explains : "Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or heap memory". And people invented that "main memory" concept so that could easier reason about such constructs. This does not make them correct.

Comment: the _only_ guarantees you have when coding in java are the ones that `JLS` gives you. And those are `program order`, `synchronizes with` and these two lead to `happens before`, which is the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: @Eugene Ok, so the main memory concept is just a way of thinking about it.  I guess that makes sense.  Thanks!